# Particle Animation as3 Layering

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, particle-system, gsap

I have battled through several tutorials to come up with the perfect particle snow effect. The only thing I need to do now is duplicate the particle effect and have a second version of it play between my background and foreground. The original I still want to keep as the top most layer. I tried wrapping the code in a function and making two of them with different names, but I got a bunch of weird errors. So instead of ruining what I already have I came here to ask for any advice on the situation. Here is my code. I am using the Greensock animation library to handle my timeline and animation.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

addChildAt(MC_BG, 0)
addChildAt(MC_FG, 2)

var tl:TimelineMax=new TimelineMax({paused:false});

function createFlake(offset) {
//create a flake (attach symbol in library with Class flake) and position on stage
var flake:Flake = new Flake();
flake.y=-50;
flake.x=randomRange(-10,1090);
flake.alpha=0;


addChild(flake);
//create timeline for each flake
var nestedTl:TimelineMax = new TimelineMax();

//how much wiggling / zig zagging
var wiggle:Number=randomRange(15,35);
//zig or zag?
wiggle=Math.random() > .5?- wiggle:wiggle;
//how fast and big
var speed:Number=randomRange(5,15);
//fade and grow
nestedTl.insert(TweenMax.to(flake, .5, {alpha:randomRange(.5,1), scaleX:speed, scaleY:speed}));
//go down
nestedTl.insert(TweenMax.to(flake,speed, {y:800}));
//zig zag
nestedTl.insert(TweenMax.to(flake, speed*.15, {x:String(wiggle), repeat:Math.floor(randomRange(1,4)), yoyo:true, ease:Sine.easeInOut}));

tl.insert(nestedTl, offset);
}

//generate random num between a min and max value
function randomRange(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
return min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
}

function init() {
//create a bunch of flakes and add them to timeline
for (var count:Number = 0; count<10000; count++) {
    var offset = count * 0.075;
    createFlake(offset);
}
}

init();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why using that many timelines? You are basically creating 10001 timelines for your snowflake effect, and 30k tweens. You'd better use an array of flakes, handle their wiggle/spin/fall by a single procedure with a single cycle (use flakes' properties to store temporary data) and create several flakes every frame so that you'll end up with constant snow. Then create two instances of the snowing MCs and have fun. The code that runs all that is a lil big for my present brain state, but it only contains unwrapped tweens interpolation code.

Comment: Well the reason I did it this way was to have the most variation in snow flakes. I tried using arrays and procedural code, but the snow always came out as patterned. I was never happy with how it fell. Also the easing Sine function either wouldn't work or would ramp up exponentially.

Comment: Use flakes' local parameters as "from", "to", "current" and "phase" values for each of the tweens involved, initialize with randoms wanted, change accordingly each frame, and the snow should no longer be patterned.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple I completely overlooked it. I made 3 blank Movie Clips, and in each of them I put a slightly modified version of this code. Then I put each movie clip on a layer in between what I wanted, and Bob's your uncle, it worked.